# Swapped images while extracting from excel using JavaScript

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

my problem is while extracting images in excel using java script the images are swapped somewhere.

using java code i could get like this
here

a94 row -- saving picture94
 a95 row -- saving picture95
 a96 row -- saving picture96

I want to save like bellow formate

a94 row -- saving picture94
 a95 row -- saving picture96
 a96 row -- saving picture95

i want to save each images with respective cell.
Please give me some idea .Do i have to change my java code.

my code is

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PictureData;

public class ReadWriteExcelFile1 {

    public static void readXLSFile() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("E://Eclips//ExcelExtract1.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

        HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row; 
        HSSFCell cell;

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        ///
        row=(HSSFRow) rows.next();
        List lst = wb.getAllPictures();
        int i=1;
        for (Iterator it = lst.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            PictureData pict = (PictureData)it.next();
            String ext = pict.suggestFileExtension();
            byte[] data = pict.getData();
            if (ext.equals("jpeg") || ext.equals("jpg") || ext.equals("png")) {
                row=(HSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                cell=(HSSFCell) cells.next();
                //if(i<=100)
                //{
                System.out.print("==>"+cell.getStringCellValue()+" == "+cell.getStringCellValue()+"."+ext+"\n");
                System.out.println(row);
              FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("E://Eclips//Output//"+cell.getStringCellValue()+"."+ext);
              out.write(data);
              out.close();
                //}
              i++;
                //}
              //if(i>=101){
             //   break;
              //}
            }
        }   
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
        readXLSFile();
        System.out.println("Export is completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not clear. You want it to be swapped or your code is swapping it?

Comment: I have attached original file is  snipping images. but if i extract the file images extracted like a94--picture94,a95--picture95,a96--picture96 like this extracted. here a95 and a96 swapped. i do not want to swap the images. I want to retrieve a94--picture94,a95--picture96,a96--picture95.

Comment: `wb.getAllPictures()` It seems like it is not keeping the original order while fetching the images.

Comment: so,what do i have to do now.Do i need to change code or Can you plz let me know what are the possibilities for solving this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795947/read-images-from-xls-file-together-with-the-references-for-their-locations/32796916#32796916

Answer (score 1):

Pictures are not assigned to Cells directly. They are related to Cells via a `ClientAnchor`. The list returned by `Workbook.getAllPictures()` is not sorted and does not have the relation to the actual cell.

You should be able to get at this information via the `Drawing` class and the `DrawingPatriarch` of a `Sheet` in a `Workbook`:

```
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
for(HSSFShape shape : ((HSSFPatriarch)drawing).getChildren()) {
    if(shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
        HSSFClientAnchor anchor = ((HSSFPicture)shape).getClientAnchor();
        ... anchor has the cell-row/column area that it is "anchored" at
    }
}
```